# Can someone tell me why my site description won't display in search results?

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt

I'm trying to get the description to display in the search results for http://www.pjarchitects.com/ I have looked at Webmaster Tools and it passes the robots.txt test but I still get this message "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."

Is there something in my head tag that might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt is cached by Google, so what you see in webmaster tools might be live but you need to wait for google to catch up. Looks like it wont be too long as other pages of your site are showing okay right now.